# Gradle Java Tomcat: Having one src folder with multiple webapps

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle

I'm trying to setup Gradle on a Java project using a Tomcat webapp. In the project it has the standard Gradle file structure with the main folder containing the src folder which has two packages, one called Yoda and the other Darth Vader.

Both of those when called will return a response depending on which is called. I want them to be on two different webapps with two different web.xml files. I haven't found any tutorials online where the code is found in one src file, a lot of them say they need to be in multiple projects. I was wondering if what I'm trying to do is possible.

Comment: So you have sources that compile into .jar and want that jar in two webapps with different web.xml ?

Comment: Yes, so that Yoda is only accessible via localhost:8888/yoda and Darth Vader is accessible from another port with a different web.xml